# Differences between FrangmentTransaction and Intent

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, fragmenttransaction

As taught by Udacity, typically one should use an intent to start a new activity (which presumably shows new/different information). But, for the project I'm currently working on I've been using FragmentTransaction to show different areas of the app. I figure this would lead to a smaller apk (b/c no java/xml files for different activities), but are there any benefits that I'm not taking into account (that would indicate that I should be using intents over FragmentTransactions)?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is up to you what you are using. Intents and FragmentTransaction have both their benefits and are useful in some situations more and in other less. I think it often depends on what you want to do with FragmentTransactions. One big benefit of Intents are the Extra Bundles with which you can share data directly, in FragmentTransaction the communication between the data is more complicated. I think you should try out both for yourself and than decide which is in certain situations useful.

Comment: When doing a fragment transaction, can't you supply a bundle via the fragment.setArguments(Bundle) method before switching out the fragments with the replace method from the FragmentTransaction class?

Comment: @JoelRobinson-Johnson yes you can, and that'll be restored if the activity instance state is saved and restored. That's why you must always have a zero-arg constructor and *not* pass any arguments to the fragment in other ways (in the constructor, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The APK size difference would be insignificant. XML and class files are compressed when archived into an APK. They are relatively small anyway.

Fragments were created to provide a way to share screen UI components between different screen / device form factors.

E.g., imagine a point of sale app with a section that shows the order line items, a section that shows the inventory that can be added to the order, and a section that shows the total dollar amounts for the order. If your app needs to work on both tablet and phone factors, you may include all three components on the screen of a tablet, but only the line items and totals on a phone. You can however re-use the line item and total fragments between both form factors. You maybe also re-use the inventory fragment, but compose it differently: on tablet it's composed on the screen along with the line items and total, but on a phone it's composed on a separate screen (embedded in a different activity).

That's the dream anyway. IMHO the complexities of having a component with a complex life cycle (fragment) living inside another component with a complex life cycle (activity) make this a questionable prospect. If you keep your fragments completely stand alone with no knowledge of the holding activity or other fragments, and keep the activity unaware of details of the fragment, it can work. Otherwise you are in for a lot of "fun".

Ironically, fragments that are composed on a screen with other fragments are typically NOT stand alone. In my example above, the order total fragment needs to know the order line items. That means you need to create a service for these two fragments to communicate this information without talking to each other directly.

Comment: I always assumed the operating system would magically connect the fragment and activity such that their lifecycles would become in-sync eventually. How exactly would a fragment not be aware of the activity lifecycle once it's inflated?

Comment: I think they are "eventually in sync", but that kind of guarantee doesn't help much when you are trying to write correct code. How WOULD a fragment be aware of the activity lifecycle? When the fragment's `onResume()` is called, has the activity's? If you find the documented answer, let me know.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CoordinatingWithActivity